# FullPageJS - fixed header z-index hides section's content

Tags: jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

Using FullPageJS for a current project with a fixed top menu that changes its height according to viewport size.

A narrow screen will stack the menu items on top of each other and a wider one will have the menu items next to each other resulting in a different height of the menu.

[Looking at the Fixed Elements demo from FullPageJS](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/fixedHeaders.html) if I for example inspect the "Fixed elements" h1 with dev tools in Firefox and go up two elements till I reach `.fp-tableCell` and there I deselect `vertical-align:middle` one can observe the text moving under the fixed header.

Well it is not actually moving but going to the top border of its container. This means the sections are always 100% of the viewport height and this means that content in sections that is not vertically aligned in the middle in a table cell element **will be hidden by fixed elements** such as a fixed navigation.

[image]

What I am trying to get is indeed a fixed header or fixed footer but not have the sections "go under" the fixed elements but actually stop at the border of the fixed element to not hide the section's content.

One way would be to inject a placeholder element with the height of the current height of the fixed element and place that under the fixed element on the same flow as the current section and therefore limit the section "sliding under" the fixed element.

[Waypoints Sticky Elements](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/) does this for dynamically created sticky or fixed elements:

> A wrapper is created around your element.
>
> This wrapper remains in a static position on the page, acting as an
>   empty placeholder for that element in the document flow while the real
>   element gains and loses fixed positioning.
>
> This wrapper element is the actual element that is used in the
>   underlying Waypoint.
>
> The wrapper height is set. This ensures the wrapper is the same height
>   as the element it wraps, even when that element becomes fixed. This
>   prevents the page layout from shifting when it does.
>
> Adds a class to the sticky element when it hits the top of the window.
>   This class is what you must style using CSS to give the sticky element
>   fixed positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: fullPage fixed element placeholder]
The approach with using a placeholder for the fixed element that gets lifted from the flow was correct.

Prepend a div, e.g. `dummy-buffer` or `placeholder` to the `.fp-tableCell` class with the height of the fixed element's height. In this example `navHeight` is the total height of the fixed element.

By giving the `placeholder` the same height as `navHeight` the rest of the content from the `.section` doesn't get cover up by the fixed element any more. In the image you can see the `placeholder` element while the `.section` is in transition.

note: I have also changed the default fullPage.css rule for this to work since I prefer to have the content of the section aligned at the top of the section.

```
.fp-tableCell {
  vertical-align:top !important;
}

$('.fp-tableCell').prepend($('<div class="dummy-buffer">DUMMY BUFFER</div>'));

var navHeightUpdate = function(){
    var navHeight = $('.navigation').outerHeight();
    console.log('Navigation Height = '+navHeight);
    $('.dummy-buffer').css('height',navHeight); 
};

navHeightUpdate();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gvsasrnw/

Answer (score 0):

You are overthinking this.

1) Give your content container a class and put a `margin-top` on that content container with the same amount of height as your header. In your case, that's about `60px`. If it's a variable height (which your example on JSFiddle is not), look into using [`calc()`](https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/) in your CSS.

HTML:
`<div class="content-area">`

CSS:

```
.content-area {
  margin-top: 60px;
  padding: 0 60px 60px;
}
```

2) Your `header` had three different position declarations on it! If you want a fixed header, it's just `position:fixed;` The code would look like this:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 1);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px #222;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

3) The height of your menu items does not have an effect on the header size when I tested it. It also didn't even need a `z-index` declaration to work correctly. You might want to look at your example again.

I updated your code for you. It works now but your question is all over the place so I'm not 100% sure on this: http://jsfiddle.net/yaJyK/98/